# using cl.exe to create a .lib or .dll

Tags: c++

I have one .c file and several .h files plus a library I'd like to link to. What is the syntax for creating a dll or lib from my .c file? I tried cl myc.c but it tried to make an exe out of it and was looking for an entrypoint..??
thanks,
sb

Answer (score 0):

try the following, 
link /DLL /OUT:dllname.dll objectfile1.obj ....
This would create a dynamic lib

Note while compiling use
cl /c something.c
This would create .obj files, it compiles the files without linking, then you can link them using the above command.

Hope you have some exported functions in the .c files..